# Determining the iframe parent

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a web page that will be embedded in iframes on multiple domains. I need to determine which domain is embedding my content.

`document.referrer` doesn't work, because I need the parent window, not the home page of the site or the page last visited prior to navigating to my page.

I don't have any control over the sites that are embedding my content.

Answer (score 0):

Because of abuse over the years Web-browsers & servers have added security.

One of them being is preventing an iframe from accessing the parent Domain unless it meets the SAME ORIGIN POLICY.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Now the HOST which your website will be embedded can allow access your to access the parent host.  Something called CORS for short.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Also check out.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Messaging

Hope that answer your question some.